# Typed DataSet in .NET Framework

Tags: .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I've the need to automatically get a DataSet from a DB table, I used internal Visual Studio tool, and between the millions of lines created, this is one of the accessor method:

```
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        public string Referente {
            get {
                try {
                    return ((string)(this[this.tableCATALOGO_Cliente.ReferenteColumn]));
                }
                catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) {
                    throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column \'Referente\' in table \'CATALOGO_Cliente\' is DBNull.", e);
                }
            }
            set {
                this[this.tableCATALOGO_Cliente.ReferenteColumn] = value;
            }
        }
```

As you can see, this code refer to the `Referente` columns. When I need to get a generic `Referente` if is `NULL` the `return` can't happen cause exception is throwned.
I resolved the issue replacing the return statement with:

```
return this[this.tableCATALOGO_Cliente.ReferenteColumn] as string;
```

Since the table contains hundred of columns I would a way to automatically this process (i.e. I would generate a `DataSet` with accessor method that doesn't thrown exception if `IS NULL` happens).

Comment: Firstly, editing generated code is a bad idea unless you never ever want to refresh that file to reflect changes. Secondly, why `DataSet`s? And in particular, why *typed* `DataSet`s? That is a pretty horrible approach, IMO. I don't usually advise `DataSet` unless there is a good reason, but *typed* `DataSet`s are *fraught* with pain. IMO, a plain POCO / DTO would be a much better option here (despite the question title, a typed `DataSet` is a very long way from being a DTO).

Comment: I used dataSet cause it was easily generated by framework. I would happly replace with something simpler with less setup as possible.

Comment: if you are after "easily generated by the framework" - I would suggest looking at LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dataset designer, select `(Empty)` instead of `(Throw Exception)` in the `NullValue`
field.
[image]

If you are accessing the dataset in code, you need to use the IsxxxNull method on the datarow: In this code, r is the datarow, _DateOpened is a Nullable (of Date)

```
  If r.IsDateOpenedNull Then
        _DateOpened = Nothing
    Else
        _DateOpened = r.DateOpened
    End If
```

Comment: How to resolve this issue when the DataType is a System.Int32 rather than System.String?

Comment: How you deal with this depends on how you are accessing the dataset.
You can type into the NullValue setting, as long as you enter something that is valid for the data type. So for an int you could enter zero, for example. Alternatively if you are accessing the dataset in code, you need to look at the IsxxxNull  and SetxxxNull methods that are generated on the datarow.

Comment: I've already thinked to the possibility of choose a 0 value, but this will trigger some constraint. What I need in that field, alas, is *NULL*. I could modify the code directly (I've already do that) but at next dataSet editing my modifications will be lost...